# Looking for an alternative to Smart Statusbar

Tags: notification-bar

Is there are way to reveal the notification bar in a full-screen app?

I have been using [Smart Statusbar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiumiu.ca.statusbar.free), which is a great little tool that reveals the bar with a gesture. Unfortunately, the app has a bug that renders some part of my phone's (Xperia Neo V) screen unresponsive. I have already emailed the developer but it seems he's no longer interested in the project. I'm now on the lookout for a perfect substitute. Any help?

I have Android 2.3.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is an alternative, as the description says...

Comment: Oh that's too bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Bird Bar.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mikedg.android.bar.lite

And now, for the rest of my 30 characters...